# Ruby: module, require and include

Tags: ruby, module, mixins

I'm trying to use Ruby modules (mixins).

I have test.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require_relative 'lib/mymodule'

class MyApp
  include MyModule
  self.hallo
end
```

and lib/mymodule.rb:

```
module MyModule
  def hallo
    puts "hallo"
  end
end
```

Quite simple setup. But it does not work :( :

```
ruby test.rb
test.rb:8:in `<class:MyApp>': undefined method `hallo' for MyApp:Class (NoMethodError)
        from test.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

Where is my error?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In short: you need to `extend` instead of `include` the module.

```
class MyApp
  extend MyModule
  self.hallo
end
```

`include` provides instance methods for the class that mixes it in.

`extend` provides class methods for the class that mixes it in.

Give [this](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/) a read.

Answer (score 14):

The issue is that you are calling `hallo` in the class definition, while you add it as an instance method (`include`).

So you could either use `extend` (`hallo` would become a class method):

```
module MyModule
  def hallo
    puts "hallo"
  end
end

class MyApp
  extend MyModule
  self.hallo
end
```

Or either call `hallo` in an instance of MyApp:

```
module MyModule
  def hallo
    puts "hallo"
  end
end

class MyApp
  include MyModule
end

an_instance = MyApp.new
an_instance.hallo
```

Answer (score 9):

Your code is working - but including a module does not do what you think it does. The class including the module will not get the methods - the objects from this class will.

So this will work :

```
class MyApp
  include MyModule
end

my_app_object = MyApp.new
my_app_object.hallo # => hallo
```

my_app_object is an object of class MyApp, which has a mixins of module MyModule. Take a look [there](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html) for a complete explanation of modules and mixins.

Answer (score 4):

```
class MyApp
  class << self
    include MyModule
  end
  self.hallo
end
```

is the same as

```
class MyApp
  extend MyModule
  self.hallo
end
```

extends just opens the class object and include the module methods. "hallo" becomes a class object aka. static method of class MyApp.

So "include" inject the methods to the instances of the receiver, in your case being "self" NOT to the object itself. "extend" inject the methods to the receiver in your case being "self".

```
self.include MyModule // inject the methods into the instances of self
self.extend MyModule // inject the methods into object self
```

At class level "self" will point to your class object which is MyApp.

Also remember that "include" and "extend" are just methods defined in module.rb.
"include" is a class object method (static-method) and "extend" is an instance method.